# Does a player have to say uno twice on the same last card?

Tags: uno

When playing with 4 or more players, if one player says "uno" when the second-to-last card is placed on the pile and now holds only one card, must they say "Uno" again at the start of their next turn, or can they say "out", or do they simply place the last card down as long as the card is playable?

Answer (score 6):

Per the [rules](http://www.unorules.com):

> The moment a player has just one card they must yell "UNO!".

So calling "Uno" happens at the point where you go from having 2 to 1 card in hand. When you play your last card, you do not need to call anything, you just go out.